# How to extract nix derivations from package files?

Tags: docker, nix, nixos

Very new to Nix and docker here. I am trying to get the License files (SPDX) for some Nix package files. I found a [git repository](https://github.com/mlieberman85/nixbom) for that and it requires the Nix derivations as input. What I have are default.nix, env.nix and shell.nix files. **How do I extract the derivations from these files?**

I don't really know how Nix works (although I tried reading a bit) and don't even need it other than this task. Any help would be appreciated. Right now I am trying the following steps.

1. Take a Nixos docker image and mount the Nix packages onto it.
2. Somehow extract the derivations from them. **(this is where I need your help)**
3. Copy the binary (of the Git link I mentioned above) from a rust debian image into this nix image. And run it on the Nix derivations.

Comment: ...in general, as someone new to Nix and Docker, I'd like to encourage you to rethink using Docker unless you have a really compelling reason to do so. To a large extent, Nix is capable of doing Docker's job better than Docker does (capable sandboxing but with more accurate and granular cache reuse, plus the ability to use `dockerTools` to output Docker images without ever using Docker itself) -- so using Docker in addition to Nix proper is adding extra complexity without much benefit.

Comment: Anyhow -- your code says it can work from Nix source _or from derivations_. The derivations are the "easy mode" here, and they're what you should use. See the `*.drv` files? Those are your derivations.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'd been using Docker to generate the SPDX files for the other packages (Rust, Node) and the reason was that it uses much less space on the computer to do it as told by my boss. But now that you recommended it, I will try to do it directly with Nix.
And regarding your second comment, although it says both expressions and derivations but when I tried running it, it required derivations. And I did not find any *.drv files. As I said the only files provided to me are the 3 I mentioned in my question.

Comment: When you build something, Nix first "plans out" the build process, creating `.drv` files; using `nix show-derivation` on the build product will tell you where those files are and decode their content into JSON. You can also use `nix-instantiate` in place of `nix-build` to just plan the build without actually running it.